# LaTeX mark Error: Infinite shrinkage found in 'page'. when using tex4ht only

Tags: tex4ht

ps. I can not paste the whole MWE here as I get error `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 501493` This is using the smallest size of the table I can make it while producing the error.

---

I have table generated by a program which is a little large. But no problem compiling it with lualatex. When using tex4ht using same commands I always use, now it gives this error which I never saw before

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug -c ./nma_mathjax.cfg main.tex "mathjax,htm,fn-in"
....

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (./main.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd))19    nil
 [1] [2]
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd)Unsupported font pzdr

Overfull \vbox (32240.63214pt too high) detected at line 1125

Overfull \vbox (32240.63214pt too high) has occurred while \output is active

! LaTeX mark Error: Infinite shrinkage found in 'page'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1125 \end{table}
                
? H

This is a coding error.

The mark region 'page' contains some infinite negative glue allowing it to
shrink to an arbitrary size. This makes it impossible to split the region
apart to get at its marks. They are lost.

?
```

Since the .tex file is large and my `nma_mathjax.cfg` is large and needed, I put these two files in the folder at the link at the bottom. I also put the .pdf compiled by lualatex with no problem.

The files are self contained and have minimal packages needed to reproduce the problem.

Simply download the .tex and .cfg files to one folder and issue the above command to see the problem.

I am using TL 2022 on Linux

```
>which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht
```

This is the .tex file preview

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %added 2/18/16  for making caption in figure same size as image
\usepackage{multirow} %added 2/21/16. To allow table with columns that span rows
\usepackage{longtable} %2/24/16  does not work in two columns
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%added OCT 28, 2018
\ifdefined\HCode 
\newcommand{\cprotect}{}
\else 
\usepackage{cprotect} %only needed to latex
\fi
    
\usepackage{pifont} %http : // ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{blue}{\Large \ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\textcolor{red}{\Large \ding{55}}}
\newcommand{\notsure}{\ding{103}} %

%this adds support to fixed width tables.
\newenvironment{fixedtabular}[2]{\gdef\tablewidth{#2}\begin{tabular}{#1}}{\end{tabular}}
%
\newcommand{\eslowast}{}
\begin{document}        
Number of problems in this table is 1066

Column notations: A is ODE degree. B is Program Number of solutions generated. C is CAS Number of solutions generated.
\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{table}
\caption{isobaric}
\begin{fixedtabular}{|p{1in}|p{5in}|p{0.6in}|p{0.6in}|p{.6in}|p{2in}|p{2in}|p{.75in}|p{.75in}|p{0.75in}|}{1100px}\hline
...... very long table here
\ifdefined\HCode\HCode{<a href="chapters/differential_equations_by_shepley_L_ross_third_edition/indexsubsection66.htm">10619</a>}\else\hyperref[10619]{10619}\fi&\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{dmath*}{}2 x^{2}+2 x y+y^{2}+\left(x^{2}+2 x y\right) y^{\prime} = 0 \end{dmath*}\end{minipage}&1&\textcolor{red}{1}&2&{isobaric}&[[\_homogeneous, class A], \_exact, \_rational, [\_Abel, 2nd type, class B]]&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&91.892\\ \hline
\ifdefined\HCode
\end{fixedtabular}
\end{table}
\else
\end{longtable}
\fi
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Any idea what is the cause of this problem and how to workaround it will be appreciated as it stopping my build now. I did not do any changes to tex4ht or to my setup for the last few months and this is first time I see this error. May be because the table size got larger? But this should not cause a problem.

The files are in [this folder](https://12000.org/tmp/tex4ht_june_2_2023/). (safe link, my own page)

Link to [tex4ht tracking bug report](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?602)

Comment: You're much more likely to get (better) answers if you reduce this to a problem that you can post here.  (Why does you saying it's a safe link to your own page make it a safe link?)

Comment: you can't need a very large example as it fails on page 2. Do not use external links

Comment: @DavidCarlisle when  I try to post the file I get `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 501493`. And this is before I even put my large .cfg file which is all is needed.  I do not understand why you think that posting such very  large text is better than one link where one can easily download the file. This is only for problems where the input happened to be very large as in this case (and will hard to copy using the mouse and can lead to error copying also). I could not make smaller size file.

Comment: @Teepeemm why do you think I  would I put a virus in my own file for?

Comment: your question  is archived here forever, and  will not make sense if the example link breaks. Also you are asking people to trace the code it is not asking too much that you put in the effort to make a reasonable example.  For example replace each paragraph  by `x\\x\\x\\x` if it has 4 lines, adjust for your example, you should be able to make an example of a few hundred characters

Comment: why do you use `tabular` with TeX4ht? I don't get any error with `longtable`, which you use with normal LaTeX. It just compiles for quite a long time, but your markup is really complex, so it is probably expecte.

Comment: @michal.h21  **why do you use tabular with TeX4ht?** I am using your code for `fixedtabular` from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653676/how-to-make-a-table-of-fixed-width-in-tex4ht-not-fixed-column-width) which uses `tabular` to make fixed width table,  I can try changing to `longtable` instead and see if it works.

Comment: @michal.h21 FYI, I changed your code to use longtable instead of tabular in the definition of  `fixedtabular` and now it compiles OK (the error is gone).  I need to test it now on my main build to see if will also work.  it will take 1-2 hrs. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser the `fixedtabular` is replacement for normal tabular, in this case, you would need a version that uses `longtable`, because this huge table needs to be broken over several pages to prevent this shrinkage error.

Comment: @michal.h21 fyi, the large file compiled OK. So it was what you said. Thanks for spotting this. If you like to make this an answer will be happy to accept, or if you think I should delete this question as a user error I can also do that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create too large table (the linked full TeX sample produced about 150 pages), but you use `tabular` with TeX4ht. It seems that it caused this issue. You can change the code to use `longtable` in both cases:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %added 2/18/16  for making caption in figure same size as image
\usepackage{multirow} %added 2/21/16. To allow table with columns that span rows
\usepackage{longtable} %2/24/16  does not work in two columns
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%added OCT 28, 2018
\ifdefined\HCode 
\newcommand{\cprotect}{}
\else 
\usepackage{cprotect} %only needed to latex
\fi
    
\usepackage{pifont} %http : // ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{blue}{\Large \ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\textcolor{red}{\Large \ding{55}}}
\newcommand{\notsure}{\ding{103}} %

%this adds support to fixed width tables.
\newenvironment{fixedtabular}[2]{\gdef\tablewidth{#2}\begin{longtable}{#1}}{\end{longtable}}
%
\newcommand{\eslowast}{}
\begin{document}        
Number of problems in this table is 1066

Column notations: A is ODE degree. B is Program Number of solutions generated. C is CAS Number of solutions generated.
\begin{table}
\caption{isobaric}
\begin{fixedtabular}{|p{1in}|p{5in}|p{0.6in}|p{0.6in}|p{.6in}|p{2in}|p{2in}|p{.75in}|p{.75in}|p{0.75in}|}{1100px}\hline
\ifdefined\HCode\HCode{<a href="chapters/differential_equations_by_shepley_L_ross_third_edition/indexsubsection66.htm">10619</a>}\else\hyperref[10619]{10619}\fi&\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{dmath*}{}2 x^{2}+2 x y+y^{2}+\left(x^{2}+2 x y\right) y^{\prime} = 0 \end{dmath*}\end{minipage}&1&\textcolor{red}{1}&2&{isobaric}&[[\_homogeneous, class A], \_exact, \_rational, [\_Abel, 2nd type, class B]]&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&91.892\\ \hline
\end{fixedtabular}
\end{table}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

The change is this:

```
\newenvironment{fixedtabular}[2]{\gdef\tablewidth{#2}\begin{longtable}{#1}}{\end{longtable}}
```

You can then also remove the unnecessary conditionals around your table.

This is the result:

[image]